# Creating a generic form loader component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was interviewed for a position and was asked this question. Obviously, I did not have an answer hence seeking help from you guys.

What I was asked:

> Create a generic loader screen that mimics form structure of the child component, so that instead of showing a spinner, we show an animated skeleton of the content to be loaded.

My idea was to clone the structure manually and animate it. This works fine but this will only work for 1 form. So question is, how can we do this?

**Ideas I thought might work:**

1. We can maybe mimic props to have a blank render and use it as a loader. Then we only need to animate the form, which we might be able to do using css. Issues with this approach would be,

   - We do not know what elements are there to animate
   - If we use redux and use `useSelector`, it will break
2. We can look into HOC. This way we know what component will be rendered. However, same issues apply here.
3. Maybe we can look into inheritance or react portals or string manipulation for some hacky way but this is half cooked idea.

Here is the sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exayo5hd/) to show animation.

The place I'm stuck is, how to get the markup of the component? Most real components will use props and might break if not available.

Comment: Any pointers/ suggestions would also help.

Comment: I can't imagine such component: jsx structure of the child component is unknown from the parent, so unless you pass some description of the structure, the skeleton will not mimic anything. If you find the answer to this please post it!

Comment: @BenjaminCaure even i have been scratching my head all day on this. I have a css based hack. Let me create a sandbox and post it but in terms of react, i doubt there is any robust way. I'll still look around and see what i can find

Comment: @bigless 3 questions here: 1. How do we control loader animation here? How do we decide loader should be visible or not? 2. If this component relies on something like `state.product` and uses `product.category.list` to loop, how do we prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I created two components, they're not pretty or close to perfect but do the job quite well I'd say. The first one is the `SkeletonWrapper` you can just wrap around your elements. You can provide it with a `isLoading` prop to indicate that *stuff* is still loading. This will map over the children and return them inside a `Skeleton`.

```js
const SkeletonWrapper = ({ children, isLoading }) => {
  if (!children) return null;
  if (!isLoading) return <>{children}</>;

  // if the components are wrapped in a Fragment replace children with the children from the Fragment
  if (children.type === React.Fragment) children = children.props.children;

  return children.map((child, idx) => <Skeleton key={idx}>{child}</Skeleton>);
};
```

The second one is the actual `Skeleton` which, to have the correct height and width, will render a `clone` of the `children` inside with a `visibilty: "hidden"`. To make sure the `spacing` is correct we remove the `margin` from the original element and put it on the `Skeleton`

I put a check for `br` elements since they're not having render a `Skeleton`.

```js
const Skeleton = ({ children }) => {
  if (children.type === "br") return null;

  const clone = React.cloneElement(children, {
    style: { ...children.props.style, visibility: "hidden", margin: 0 },
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background:
          "linear-gradient(90deg, lightgray 45%, #ddd 55%, lightgray 100%)",
        backgroundSize: "200% 200%",
        animation: "pulse 1.5s ease-in-out 0.5s infinite",
        borderRadius: "12px",
        margin: children.props.style?.margin ?? "0",
        width: "fit-content",
      }}
    >
      {clone}
    </div>
  );
};
```

To see it in action please check the [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-austin-k2o256?file=/src/App.js) in a code sandbox. Note that it will not be exactly the same since the `Skeleton` has a `fit-content` and not really `flex` support.

Truely loved this question, even if its not the answer you were looking for, it was an awesome challenge, thanks!

Comment: This is a good approach. Let me play around it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full solution but I would recommend using material-ui Skeleton
component instead of applying the style manually. It also has few other props that might make some other solutions possible.

We used Skeleton in a project where I work but we customized each one of the components and didn't create a common loader as you need here.